# How to execute a shell command with root permission from swift

Tags: macos, shell, swift, root, nstask

I am new on Swift and I am trying to create a very simple application that executes a root shell command when you press a round button.

I have found the following link online, that explains how to execute a shell command with user permission on swift, but it doesn't tell how to do it with root privileges: http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/25/how-to-execute-shell-commands-from-swift/

How can I do it?

Comment: do you know about `sudo`? but it's possible that `swift` won't allow `sudo` commands. (I have no direct experience with Swift, so YRMV) Good luck.

Comment: nice question, and it's going to be a potentially complicated answer.  If I had to answer it, my solution would either use [some form of NSTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697454/nstask-command-line-tools-and-root) or even better (and more modern), [a tool that makes use of SMJobBless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134841/writing-a-privileged-helper-tool-with-smjobbless), [which *does* have a Swift interface](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/ServiceManagement/Reference/ServiceManagement_header_reference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SMJobBless)

Comment: I am thinking about using pipe.fileHandleForWriting.writeData to send the password to sudo, but I have not found a lot of documentation in that direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick-and-dirty:

```
NSAppleScript(source: "do shell script \"sudo whatever\" with administrator " +
    "privileges")!.executeAndReturnError(nil)
```

Alternatively look into privileged helper tools but expect that to be much more complicated.

Comment: nice suggestion, but this doesn't use `NSTask` and there might be a good reason why one would want to use `NSTask` ... or something similar at least